# Find missing values by linear interpolation (time serie)

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, linear-interpolation

I have these `data.frame` called `df1` which represents each month over three years (36 rows x 4 columns) :

```
       Year Month       v1       v2       v3
1  2015     1 15072.73 2524.102 17596.83
2  2015     2 15249.54 2597.265 17846.80
3  2015     3 15426.35 2670.427 18096.78
4  2015     4 15603.16 2743.590 18346.75
5  2015     5 15779.97 2816.752 18596.72
6  2015     6 15956.78 2889.915 18846.69
7  2015     7 16133.59 2963.077 19096.67
8  2015     8 16310.40 3036.240 19346.64
9  2015     9 16487.21 3109.402 19596.61
10 2015    10 16664.02 3182.565 19846.58
11 2015    11 16840.83 3255.727 20096.56
12 2015    12 17017.64 3328.890 20346.53
13 2016     1 17018.35 3328.890 20347.24
14 2016     2 17019.05 3328.890 20347.94
15 2016     3 17019.76 3328.890 20348.65
16 2016     4 17020.47 3328.890 20349.36
17 2016     5 17021.17 3328.890 20350.06
18 2016     6 17021.88 3328.890 20350.77
19 2016     7 17022.58 3328.890 20351.47
20 2016     8 17023.29 3328.890 20352.18
21 2016     9 17024.00 3328.890 20352.89
22 2016    10 17024.70 3328.890 20353.59
23 2016    11 17025.41 3328.890 20354.30
24 2016    12 17026.12 3328.890 20355.01
25 2017     1 17023.94 3328.890 20352.83
26 2017     2 17021.76 3328.890 20350.65
27 2017     3 17019.58 3328.890 20348.47
28 2017     4 17017.40 3328.890 20346.29
29 2017     5 17015.22 3328.890 20344.11
30 2017     6 17013.04 3328.890 20341.93
31 2017     7 17010.86 3328.890 20339.75
32 2017     8 17008.68 3328.890 20337.57
33 2017     9 17006.50 3328.890 20335.39
34 2017    10 17004.32 3328.890 20333.21
35 2017    11 17002.14 3328.890 20331.03
36 2017    12 17002.14 3328.890 20331.03
```

I want to interpolate all of these values in order to obtain interpolated values for all days of each month. They are in the `data.frame` called `df2` (1096 x 1).

`df2` looks like :

```
  seq(start, end, by = "days")
1                   2015-01-01
2                   2015-01-02
3                   2015-01-03
4                   2015-01-04
5                   2015-01-05
6                   2015-01-06
```

By this way I should obtain an output `data.frame` called `results` of 1096 rows (365 days (2015)+ 366 days(2016) + 365 days(2017)) and 4 columns.

I have tried with `approx`:

```
results <- as.data.frame(approx(x = df1, y = NULL, xout = df2 ,
                             method = "linear"))
```

But it returns:

```
         x  y
1 2015-01-01 NA
2 2015-01-02 NA
3 2015-01-03 NA
4 2015-01-04 NA
5 2015-01-05 NA
6 2015-01-06 NA
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: "so at least two complete (x, y) pairs are required (for method = "linear", one otherwise)." from the help. You should provide y. I am not sure that it will do all column at once, you should maybe use `lapply`.  Consider use of normal regression functions like `lm` or `lmer` and a defined model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here is a solution which uses `data.table`.

The OP has provided data points for each month of 2015 to 2017. He hasn't defined the day of month to which the values are attributed to. Furthermore, he hasn't specified what type of interpolation he expects.

So, the given data look as follows (only `v1` shown for simplicity):

[image]

Note that deliberately the monthly value was assigned to the first day of the month.

There are [different ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) to interpolate data. We will look at two of them.

#### Piecewise constant interpolation

As only one data point per month is given we can safely assume that the value is representative for each day of the respective month:

[image]

(Plotted with `geom_step()`)

For interpolation, the base R function `approx()` is used. `approx()` is applied on all value columns `v1`, `v2`, `v3` with help of `lapply()`.

But first we need to turn the year-month into a full-flegded date (including day). The first day of the month has been chosen deliberately. Now, the data points in `df1` are attributed to the dates 2015-01-01 to 2017-12-01. Note, that there is no given value for 2017-12-31 or 2018-01-01.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
# create date (assuming the 1st of month)
setDT(df1)[, date := as.IDate(paste(Year, Month, 1, sep = "-"))]
# create sequence of days covering the whole period
ds <- seq(as.IDate("2015-01-01"), as.IDate("2017-12-31"), by = "1 day")
# perform interpolation
cols = c("v1", "v2", "v3")
results <- df1[, c(.(date = ds), lapply(.SD, function(y) 
  approx(x = date, y = y, xout = ds, method = "constant", rule = 2)$y)), 
  .SDcols = cols]
results
```

> ```
>             date       v1       v2       v3
>    1: 2015-01-01 15072.73 2524.102 17596.83
>    2: 2015-01-02 15072.73 2524.102 17596.83
>    3: 2015-01-03 15072.73 2524.102 17596.83
>    4: 2015-01-04 15072.73 2524.102 17596.83
>    5: 2015-01-05 15072.73 2524.102 17596.83
>   ---                                      
> 1092: 2017-12-27 17002.14 3328.890 20331.03
> 1093: 2017-12-28 17002.14 3328.890 20331.03
> 1094: 2017-12-29 17002.14 3328.890 20331.03
> 1095: 2017-12-30 17002.14 3328.890 20331.03
> 1096: 2017-12-31 17002.14 3328.890 20331.03
> ```

By specifying `rule = 2`, `approx()` was told to use the last given values (the ones  for 2017-12-01) to complete the sequence up to 2017-12-31.

The result can be plotted on top of the given data points.

[image]

#### Piecewise linear interpolation

For drawing a line segement, two points must be given. In order to draw line segments for 36 intervals (months), we need 37 data points. Unfortunately, the OP has given only 36 data points. We would need an additional data point for 2018-01-01 to draw a line for the last month.

One of the options in this case is to assume that the values for the last month are constant. This is what `approx()` does when `method = "linear"` and `rule = 2` is specified.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
# create date (assuming the 1st of month)
setDT(df1)[, date := as.IDate(paste(Year, Month, 1, sep = "-"))]
# create sequence of days covering the whole period
ds <- seq(as.IDate("2015-01-01"), as.IDate("2017-12-31"), by = "1 day")
# perform interpolation
cols = c("v1", "v2", "v3")
results <- df1[, c(.(date = ds), lapply(.SD, function(y) 
  approx(x = date, y = y, xout = ds, method = "linear", rule = 2)$y)), 
  .SDcols = cols]
results

            date       v1       v2       v3
   1: 2015-01-01 15072.73 2524.102 17596.83
   2: 2015-01-02 15078.43 2526.462 17604.89
   3: 2015-01-03 15084.14 2528.822 17612.96
   4: 2015-01-04 15089.84 2531.182 17621.02
   5: 2015-01-05 15095.54 2533.542 17629.08
  ---                                      
1092: 2017-12-27 17002.14 3328.890 20331.03
1093: 2017-12-28 17002.14 3328.890 20331.03
1094: 2017-12-29 17002.14 3328.890 20331.03
1095: 2017-12-30 17002.14 3328.890 20331.03
1096: 2017-12-31 17002.14 3328.890 20331.03
```

[image]

In the sample dataset, the values for 2016 and 2017 are rather flat. Constant interpolation for the last month isn't eye-catching,  anyway.

Comment: Do you think it could be possible to fix the first and the last day of each month, in order to obtain all days over a year? In your answer, results has only 335 rows instead of 365 (Month of December is missing)

Comment: We need `n + 1` break points to define `n` intervals. Your sample dataset contained only 12 data points which are sufficient to interpolate 11 month. If you would supply the data for 1st of January, 2016 in addition to the other 12 data points in 2015, we could interpolate also December.

Comment: I have just edited the post. Could you explain a little bit more your process please

Comment: @Sebastien_H, I have completely rewritten my answer. Hope, i could have made my points clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. There are just some details that should be added.

First of all, I have an impression, that you have omitted the year value from your data. However, it's important to have a year value when working with the dates. I suppose, you data should look like that:

```
     Year Month   v1      v2          v3
1     2015     1 15072.73 2524.102   17596.83
2     2015     2 15249.54 2597.265   17846.80
3     2015     3 15426.35 2670.427   18096.78
4     2015     4 15603.16 2743.590   18346.75
5     2015     5 15779.97 2816.752   18596.72
6     2015     6 15956.78 2889.915   18846.69
7     2015     7 16133.59 2963.077   19096.67
8     2015     8 16310.40 3036.240   19346.64
9     2015     9 16487.21 3109.402   19596.61
10    2015    10 16664.02 3182.565   19846.58
11    2015    11 16840.83 3255.727   20096.56
12    2015    12 17017.64 3328.890   20346.53
```

Another question is which day of the month is implied for the monthly values given by `df1`. Let's suppose that it is the first day of the month. Then the solution may be obtained that

```
data_names <- c("v1", "v2", "v3")
res_set <- lapply(
    function(var_name) approx(
        x = as.Date(paste(df1$Year, df1$Month, "01", sep = "-")), 
        y = df1[, var_name], xout = df2), 
    X = data_names)
# name each item of the list to make further work simpler
names(res_set) <- data_names
print(str(res_set))
```

Note, please, that the result of `lapply()` is a list. Some additional work is needed to obtain a desirable format. If you need a single data frame for all the variables, than you may use:

```
res_df <- data.frame(x = df2, lapply(res_set,`[[`,  "y"))
```

If you prefer a list of two-column data dframes, than an option is:

```
res_list <- lapply(res_set, as.data.frame)
```

Comment: The OP says he expects a data.frame with four columns. Your result is a list with 3 elements, each with 2 vectors. Turned into a data.frame by `as.data.frame(res_set)` ,it still has 6 columns.

Comment: Why why I get this error when I run lapply:  Error in approx(x = as.Date(paste(df1$Year, df1$Month, "01", sep = "-")),  : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double' . I don't understand the meaning

Comment: @Sebastien_H It means that a list is supplied where a vector is expected. I have assumed that df2 is a vector. If it is a list than its' items should be extracted with $ or [[.